# Google Sign-In backend server authentication

Tags: android, authentication, token, backend, google-signin

I'm writing an Android app for voice chatting and decided to use Google Sign-In for a simple user authentication with my backend server. However, I don't understand how the app should authenticate with my backend. When a user signs-in using his Google account and I receive the ID token, I can send the ID token to the server, then the server verifies it. And what's then? How to authenticate following requests, for example when the user sends/receives a voice message and the app needs to upload/download the message to/from the server? Server needs to know which user is making the request, but the ID token is inappropriate because it expires soon and its integrity verification is a complex and relatively long process.

Comment: hey Salivan, did you ever found a resolution or approach for this situation?

Comment: I think Utsav Dusad's answer is the most appropriate.

Comment: So every consequent request with maybe an Authorization header containing the idToken value? If so, and given that the idToken is a JWT, maybe as Authorization: Bearer {idToken} ?

Comment: Yes, you could send it to your backend server as an Authorization header, but JWT instead of Bearer, and then on your server have means to validate it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Google Sign-in API: Following steps are involved:

- User signs in Google using the iOS/Android application.
- Google returns tokenid (and some extra information. See the [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in) for extra information) to the client (iOS/Android App).
- Client sends the tokenid to the backend server.
- server uses Google client API (or call google end point by making GET request but beware it has a network delay associated with it) to verify the integrity of the token. In this step certain criteria should be satisfied. See [Here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth).
- GoogleAPI returns some information to the server. What kind of information? 
  Something like this:

> {u'picture':
>   u'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-RD4yn7rqIc8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAALQI/9Ab_kR3_CII/s96-c/photo.jpg',
>   u'sub': u'10270538098780639-55', u'family_name': u'Dusad', u'iss':
>   u'https://accounts.google.com', u'email_verified': True, u'name':
>   u'Utsav Dusad', u'at_hash': u'BMjN0mWeOMqVVBhjW_W9A', u'given_name':
>   u'Utsav', u'exp': 1484582338, u'azp':
>   u'85959433390-npk1ss7juimjqt5hrlhm7v2fj2u7593f.apps.googleusercontent.com',
>   u'iat': 1484578738, u'locale': u'en-GB', u'email':
>   u'utsavdusad@gmail.com', u'aud':
>   u'85959433390-npk1ss7juimjqt5hrlhm7v2fj2u7593f.apps.googleusercontent.com'}

sub: Subject. userID. Don't use email id as primarykey as it may change. use userID.

> An identifier for the user, unique among all Google accounts and never
>   reused. A Google account can have multiple emails at different points
>   in time, but the sub value is never changed. Use sub within your
>   application as the unique-identifier key for the user.

For detailed information see [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#obtainuserinfo):

- Server returns success login to the client.
- client make subsequent (HTTP POST, GET) requests with tokenID.
- Server serves the data by verifying the idtoken and checking 'sub' info (sub is the unique identity of a user).

Comment: You say at the end to make subsequent HTTPS GET/POST requests with the ID token (provided by Google Sign In). I like this approach. But what happens if the token expires? Would we just return 'TOKEN_EXPIRED' to the client, then the client would get a new ID token via sliently signing in again, then the client would proceed to attempt the request again?

Comment: @Antinous Yes, in that case, the user would have to do the silent sign in order to get a valid token and then only he can proceed with the request.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the explanation you need is at:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#verify-the-integrity-of-the-id-token

It explains:

> After you receive the ID token by HTTPS POST, you must verify the
>   integrity of the token. To verify that the token is valid, ensure that
>   the following criteria are satisfied:
>
> The ID token is a JWT that is properly signed with an appropriate
>   Google public key (available in JWK or PEM format). The value of aud
>   in the ID token is equal to one of your app's client IDs. This check
>   is necessary to prevent ID tokens issued to a malicious app being used
>   to access data about the same user on your app's backend server. The
>   value of iss in the ID token is equal to accounts.google.com or
>   https://accounts.google.com. The expiry time (exp) of the ID token has
>   not passed. If your authentication request specified a hosted domain,
>   the ID token has a hd claim that matches your Google Apps hosted
>   domain.

It states:

> Rather than writing your own code to perform these verification steps,
>   we strongly recommend using a Google API client library for your
>   platform, or calling our tokeninfo validation endpoint.

It goes on to show you exactly what you need to do.

Comment: Nope it absolutely doesn't answer my question. So should I send the ID token with every request? Because that's ridiculous. :)

Comment: You just showed how to verify the token, and I asked how to authorize following requests after the one that verified the token.

Comment: Okay, I think what you're looking for then is monitoring the user's session ( related topic: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/session-state) Once user is authenticated, the session can be "trusted".

Comment: with google sign in you should authenticate user once, then get a user app specific auth token to keep user session - you don't need google authorizations for subsequent requests.